# Using Parameters on a Google Drive API request?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am trying to make an request on the Google Drive API, and I had some questions. I want to search a specific folder for files, so I use the `q` parameter in my request as follows, for some string (in this case called `example`):

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': "'example' in parents"
});
```

Now, if I want to do the same thing, but instead pass a parameter in to the call, as follows, it does not work.

```
var test = 'example'
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
   'q': "'test' in parents"
});
```

Is there some way that I can pass a variable into the API call?

Comment: shouldn't the call be `"q":test+" in parents"`? Your current snippet takes 'test' as part of the string, not calling the `test` variable.

Comment: I tried that as well, but when I try it out, I get a 400 error code. Again, it works if I directly post the value `example`

Answer (score 0):

Its probably returning 400 because you're not following the right syntax for using `q`. The [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#fields) section of the documentation discusses this. Basically, `q` needs to have name, operator and value passed to have a valid query.

Hopefully this helps with your issue.

Happy coding!

Comment: But it works properly when I have a hardcoded string in the `q` parameter. Can you give me an example of a valid query? Thanks